# Detecting which views are touched within swipre over gridlayout

Tags: android, gridview, touch-event, motionevent

I am currently working on an application which should be able to detect which individual textviews in a gridlayout are touched. Goal is to set the background color of the touched views to a different color. I am creating the views like this:

```
for (int row = 1; row < 13; row++) {
        for (int col=0; col<24; col++) {
            TextView tv = new TextView(this);
            GridLayout.LayoutParams params = new GridLayout.LayoutParams(GridLayout.spec(row), GridLayout.spec(col));
            params.width = (int)(screenWidth / 24);
            params.height = (int) (tenth_heigth * 8) / 12 ;
            tv.setLayoutParams(params);
            tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            tv.setText("A");
            tv.setTextAppearance(this, android.R.style.TextAppearance_Large);
            gridLayout.addView(tv, params);     
        }
    }
```

I tried to do this with an overridden onTouchEvent method within the activity, but so far I had no luck achieving my goal. What's the best way to do this?

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN :
                    // would like to set the background color of the touched view to blue
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE :
        // would like to set the background color of the touched views to red
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP :

        // set the background color to purple
        break;
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

I would appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction. Thanks a lot!